# XML Twig always editing the XML

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I'm sure I'm not using it correctly, my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new( pretty_print  => 'indented',
                twig_handlers => { '//Item[@PartNumber]' => \&_pitem
                                  },
)->parsefile_inplace( 'order2.xml', '.bak' );

sub _pitem {
    $_->set_text(...) if (....);
}
```

If there are no elements matching that XPath expression in the XML, seems like the XML turns out to be empty...it truncates the file.
my desired behavior is: 
avoid editing the XML at all, if no elements are matched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `parsefile_inplace` then the file will be overwritten in any case.

You need either to `flush` the file, or manage the creation of a new file yourself if necessary.

You can use the code from [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig) as a basis.

Answer (score 1):

You have written nothing that *outputs* any XML.

You should use `twig_roots` like this

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_roots               => { '//Item[@PartNumber]' => \&_pitem },
    twig_print_outside_roots => 1,
    pretty_print             => 'indented',
);

$twig->parsefile_inplace( 'order2.xml', '.bak' );

sub _pitem {
    $_->set_text(...) if (....);
    $_->print;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the _pitem, you have to

```
$_->flush;
```